# BrowserRouter in React leading to "invalid hook calls"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I'm new to React, and I'm trying to set up paths using BrowserRouter, Route and Routes.
Thus far, my code looks like the following

```js
import React from "react"
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./Login";

function App() {

    return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>App page</h1>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/login">
                     <Login />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

However, nothing's appearing on the browser page - the console output looks like the following
[image: error message in console log]

The error seems to be with the router bits, since when I take those lines out, things in the `h1` tag seem to be printing fine. Would you know how to fix this/what might be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the contents of package.json?

Comment: ...or better append output of command `npm ls react react-dom`; I think you may have multiple versions of React and/or React-Dom installed

Answer (score 2):

Login is not a `<Route>` component. All component children of `<Routes>` must be a `<Route>`or `<React.Fragment>`.

try this:

```
import React from "react"
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./Login";

function App() {

    return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>App page</h1>
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    </div>
  )
```